# A card is drawn from a pack of 52 cards at random. What's the probability that it is neither a spade or jack?

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> A card is drawn from a pack of $52$ cards at random. What's the probability that it is neither a spade ($\spadesuit$) or jack?

I got $$\frac{12}{52}\cdot \frac{4}{52}=\frac{48}{2704}=1.78\%$$ Did I do this right?

Comment: No, very far from the truth.  You will be happy if the card is neither a spade nor a Jack. How many cards will make you happy?  Lots. If you do not know an efficient way of counting, do it inefficiently.

Comment: work with complements of sets [neither $A$ nor $B$] $\Leftrightarrow$ [not (<$A$ and not $B$> or <$A$ and $B$> or <not $A$ and $B$>) ]

Comment: It would have been **much** better if you had explained your thought process instead of just writing down a more or less random formula.

Comment: Do you even know the compound inequality that every probability must satisfy? Obviously not.

Answer (score 4):

No.  If your first fraction had been $13/52$, that would have been the probability that the card was both a spade *and* a jack, but that would have been much easier obtained as the probability of drawing the jack of spades: $1/52$.  In point of fact, the probability you ended up with, $3/169$, is less than the probability of drawing any individual card, so it cannot be correct.

One good way of arriving at the correct result is to think of how many cards are neither a jack nor a spade.  Of the $52$ cards, $52-13 = 39$ are not spades; but of those, $3$ are jacks, leaving $36$.  So the desired probability is $36/52 = 9/13$.

Answer (score 0):

There are $4$ jacks in the deck and $13$ spades. However $1$ jack is a spade so we have a total of $16$ cards which are either a jack or a spade. Therefore there are $52-16=36$ cards which are not a jack or a spade. Thus the probability is $36/52$.

Comment: Why am I not multiplying them separately?

Comment: For this question, the probability is (#number of cards not a spade or a Jack) / (#number of cards). We know the number of cards is 52, and its easy to calculate how many cards are not a spade or a jack so calculating the probability is easy.